# Does preview link in facebook post reveal user?

Tags: facebook

I know that Facebook uses https which mean all information is encrypted. But when I view posts on FB, I often see preview of links, which include pictures and text.

Since FB is on https, does it mean all previews are sent from FB server? Or the link is embedded from the source?

If the preview is from the link source, then will it reveal user that viewing a page on FB to the source link?

Comment: They're most-likely using a proxy to relay the information like Slack does but you could quickly test it out with a server of yours.

Comment: I don;t have any server so I can not test it myself, so I asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, because Facebook relays the information to you.**

I ran a test two months ago by creating a webpage that would send me an email each time it was visited. Immediately after posting the link as a status, with privacy set to "Only me", I received the email with an IP address from Facebook and not my own.

It's likely they do this to avoid exposing users out of their control via posting links similar to this.

Answer (score 3):

> does it mean all previews are sent from FB server? Or the link is embedded from the source?

When you share a page on social media, the platform (in this case Facebook) pulls in certain information from the embedded webpage, including the title, author information, page summary, and often an image. More information can be specified in the html header in meta tags. See this link for more information on meta tags: https://moz.com/blog/meta-data-templates-123

> If the preview is from the link source, then will it reveal user that viewing a page on FB to the source link?

If you log in to a website using your facebook credentials, then that website is pulling information from your Facebook profile to store in their database about you, so you would be identifiable. Otherwise when you post a link, if a website user has a Facebook developer account, they can collect metrics about your usage, which can be viewed in aggregate via the Facebook Insight API. Insights works in a similar fashion to Google Analytics, in that it will show a site owner that you viewed the site and some information about you, but not your name. However, given enough information, you can still be identified by metadata. See this blog for more information about Facebook Insights https://blog.kissmetrics.com/guide-to-facebook-insights/ and also look up Facebook's privacy policy for more information on how they use your information.